# Fedora 20 and skype screen sharing

Tags: skype, fedora20

I use Skype 4.3 on Fedora 20, and I have a problem with screen sharing. (btw, the problem also happens with 4.2.*).

When I share my screen with another Skype client (ipad, windows... doesn't matter), my screen on the other client is just so noisy. Or the quality is so poor. Hard to define.

I found a [similar topic](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/4-2-0-13-Screen-Sharing-quot-fuzziness-quot/td-p/2924581) on the internet, but the solution doesn't work for me.

Anyone faced with similar issue ?